# jQuery Mobile not building first dynamic page when inside Phonegap deviceready

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a mobile app using JQM 1.3.0 & Phonegap.  The app makes web service calls and populates the content of all pages with AJAX.  When developing in the browswer and calling my scripts directly, everything works fine:

```
applicationScripts()

function applicationScripts(){

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1, #page2,  #page3, #page4,  #page5", function() {

        $.ajax({
            //make call and populate content.
        })
    });
}
```

However, once I call the function from inside the deviceready listener, #page1 doesn't get data.  Pages 2-5 work fine.  (I also tried nesting the event listener inside of a `<body onload="onLoad()">` function but had similar results.)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', applicationScripts, false);

function applicationScripts(){

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1, #page2,  #page3, #page4,  #page5", function() {

        $.ajax({
            //#page1 not getting content. 
        })
    });
}
```

Here is the head of my document.  All of my scripts are in the application.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.ios.js"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js" ></script>
```

I don't know if it is a timing issue with some files/events being loaded before others, but it seems like I have tried every conceivable combination of script orders and different ways to call 'deviceready'.    Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have done couple of PhoneGap projects and I never have bind the page events inside the `deviceready` function.

Simply bind the page events in the js file. It works just fine. After all I have 3 PhoneGap projects running on production and none of the projects got issues reported due to this reason.

I used `deviceready` function in my project to disable the back button, not to initalise any pages etc etc.

Hope that would help you out.

Comment: I am using the Geolocation API as well.  Should I be leaving those scripts inside the `deviceready`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the code below:

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
  deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}

$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
  jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});

$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);

function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
  $(document).on("pageinit", "#page1, #page2,  #page3, #page4,  #page5", function() {
    $.ajax({
          //Do something here
    })
});
}
```